# Can an LWC access a cookie set in a different domain?

Tags: lightning-web-components, digital-experience, cookies

I have a customer who runs a support site via a Digital Experience.  They are interested in setting a cookie in their website ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and have it be available to a Lightning Web Component in their Digital Experience site (help.example.com).

Is something like this possible?  If so, how should such a cookie be constructed?  Would it need to use something like RWS ([Related Website Sets](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/related-website-sets-integration/))?

Does something need to be setup on the Salesforce side to allow access to the cookie?

Comment: If they're using Locker Service or Lightning Web Security, I believe the access will be blocked, as cookies are sandboxed by namespace. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You're absolutely right, @sfdcfox.  It's not cookie construction that prevents LWC from reading those cookies.  It's the sandboxing applied by the Salesforce security frameworks (Locker Service or LWS) the prevents the cookies from being read.  Thank you very much!